# How strict is Lufthansa with the pet crate sizes for excess baggage?

Tags: luggage, lufthansa, pets

I'm flying with my cat as excess luggage. Luftansa says the crate needs to be 60cm L x 45cm W x 40cm H but all the crates I can find online are 41cm in height. I don't want them to deny entry to my pet on the flight at the airport, just because his crate is a cm taller than their specifications.

Comment: "I'm flying with my cat as excess luggage"  HEH that's a great sentence  :)

Comment: My gut instinct is you'd be fine.  Those crates are expensive, you don't want to buy another one.  Perhaps phone Lufthansa - I'm pretty sure it's fine.  it's not an "exact" measurement (they do not have to, for example, 'squeeze them in' to some device or holder - they just don't want you to bring a huge one).  Phone them!

Comment: @Dorothy:  As far as I can tell, this question is asking about pet crate dimensions for pets traveling as cargo, while the question you identified is about pets traveling in the passenger cabin.  See [Lufthansa's requirements here](http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/us/infoservice/baggage?nodeid=305559505&l=en);  from the dimensions given, the OP appears to be asking about a "medium" animal to be transported in the cargo hold.

Comment: This is quite obviously not a duplicate of that, unless Lufthansa loads passengers in the cargo hold, that is. That said, we need an additional closing reason for "Why don't you just ask them? It's free."